# Не показывается видео

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

```css
.page {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
     
    .page-video {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
     
    .page-video:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
     
    .page-video .video {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
     
    .content {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }

header{
    color: black;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: url("Massage.mp4");
}
body{
    background-color: black;
}
p{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    
    .page {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
     
    .page-video {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
     
    .page-video:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
     
    .page-video .video {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
     
    .content {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }

header{
    color: black;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: url("Massage.mp4");
}
body{
    background-color: black;
}
p{
    color: white;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header> MassagePerfect </header>

    <div class="page">

        <div class="page-video">
            <video class="video" loop="loop" autoplay="" muted="" poster="Massage.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
            
        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="title">Video background for block</h1>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <p> Хотите получить идеальный массаж от нашей супер-дупер компании?</p>
        <p> Позвоните нам - и получите отличную консультацию и записывание на сеанс!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <video src="rabbit320.webm" controls> ?

Answer (score 0):

У вашего тега `<video>`вместо атрибута `src="Massage.mp4"` задан атрибут `poster`, замените, и если в той же папке что и ваш html файл лежит видео, оно будет проигрываться.